# Assign list of character vectors to new data.table column in R

Tags: r, list, vector, data.table

I'm trying to parse a string with a delimiter with every pair of substrings split by the delimiter. Once I have that I want to assign the resulting list of character vector pairs to a new column in a data table, but currently I'm running into an error. here should be a MWE:

```
library(stringr)
decompose_string_pairs <- function(n_string = ""){
  n <- str_count(n_string,"\\|")[[1]] + 1
  string_pairs <- list()
  
  for(i in n:2){
    n1 <- str_split(n_string, "\\|")[[1]][i]
    for(j in (i-1):1){
      n2 <- str_split(n_string,"\\|")[[1]][j]
      temp_pair <- list(c(n1,n2))
      string_pairs <- c(string_pairs,temp_pair)
    }
  }
  return(string_pairs)
}
test <- decompose_string_pairs("1|2|3")
test
```

which returns the expected list of character vectors:

```
> test
[[1]]
[1] "3" "2"

[[2]]
[1] "3" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "2" "1"
```

Where I'm running into trouble is then assigning this result to a new column in a data table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(strings <- c("1|2|3","1|4"))
dt[, parsed_list := decompose_string_pairs(strings)]
```

But on running this I get:

```
Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'parsed_list'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

yet when I try to modify the `dt` assignment with:

```
dt[, parsed_list := rep(decompose_string_pairs(strings))]
```

or

```
dt[, parsed_list := rep_len(decompose_string_pairs(strings))]
```

The assignment doesn't work and I get the same error for the first and

```
Error in rep_len(decompose_string_pairs(strings)) : 
  argument "length.out" is missing, with no default
```

for the second.

How can I store lists in columns of a dt? I know it's possible but I can't figure out the structure I need at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your function isn't vectorized. It only expectes one value at a time. If you run

```
decompose_string_pairs(c("1|2|3","1|4"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "3" "2"
# [[2]]
# [1] "3" "1"
# [[3]]
# [1] "2" "1"
```

you see you only get the first output. If you vectorize your function, it would work

```
decompose_string_pairs_vec <- Vectorize(decompose_string_pairs)
dt[, parsed_list := decompose_string_pairs_vec(strings)]
dt
#       V1 parsed_list
# 1: 1|2|3   <list[3]>
# 2:   1|4   <list[1]>
```

Comment: So does this mean that when you're using data.table's `:=` operator it's passing the entire column as a vector? I though the common syntax of `dt[,new_var := lapply(.SD,sum,na.rm=T),.SDcols = "col"]` was passing the `"col"` as a list to the function and iterating over it. Am I way off?

Comment: For efficiency, functions apply over an entire column at a time. With `.SDcols` you iterate over columns, not rows.

Answer (score 0):

We may do a group by approach and wrap the output in a `list`

```
dt[,  parsed_list := .(.(decompose_string_pairs(strings))), by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

-output

```
> dt
   strings parsed_list
1:   1|2|3   <list[3]>
2:     1|4   <list[1]>
> dt$parsed_list
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "3" "2"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "3" "1"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "2" "1"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "4" "1"
```

---

We may also do this with `combn` after splitting

```
dt[, parsed_list := .(lapply(strsplit(strings, "|", fixed = TRUE), 
     combn, 2, simplify = FALSE))]
> dt
   strings parsed_list
1:   1|2|3   <list[3]>
2:     1|4   <list[1]>
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(strings = c("1|2|3","1|4"))
```